# SQL Query help needed for address part extraction

Tags: sql

How can I extract House no, street direction & address from a full address in SQL?

**The full address for example is**: `3212 S Lindsey Street`

I want as following

```
House no: 3212  
Street direction: S  
Address: Lindsey Street
```

Comment: I wouldn't. Parsing address information is error prone and in "larger" sets of data there will always be variations of how data was persisted / collected. Collect and store it in different fields (columns). If you have no choice then see if there are services that can do it for you (parsing) and then store that result in different fields.

Comment: Does your data always conform to the format <number><space><letter><space><street>?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @Stu, yes it's in same format

Comment: @debfinal Then you can use simple string parsing or create a scalar function; the answer will depend on your particylar RDBMS which you still have not indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform you're using you can extract the words from your value with split functions like `SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position)` (PostgreSQL) and then concate them as you like.

```
SELECT split_part(address,' ',1) as no, 
split_part(address' ', 2) as direction
split_part(address' ', 3) || split_part(address,' ', 4) as street
FROM schema.table
```

Or for more complex things there are RegEx functions available as well.

But as Igor mentioned this is very fault prone since an address does not always have the same format. E.g. there can be the `Lindsay Street` and the `Lindsay Lohan Street`